# "I got an error after reinstalling nodejs"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1161   return process.dlopen(module,
> path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
> ^
>
> Error: The module '\?\G:\Discord
> bot\Bot\ZackyBot\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node' was
> compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION
> 83. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 88. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
> at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1161:18)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
> at Object. (G:\Discord bot\Bot\ZackyBot\node_modules\canvas\lib\bindings.js:3:18)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
> at Object. (G:\Discord bot\Bot\ZackyBot\node_modules\canvas\lib\canvas.js:9:18)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32) {   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED' }

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398592/node-js-error-return-process-dlopenmodule-path-makelongfilename

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE\_MODULE\_VERSION 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you installed a newer version of NodeJS than earlier. But you did not compile your project `ZackyBot`'s node modules using the current version of the NodeJS you installed.

I would suggest you go to your project directory and clean all your node modules. Then reinstall them again. Follow the steps below:

1. Delete `node_modules` directory inside `ZackyBot` directory
2. Execute `npm install` command on a terminal from `ZackyBot` directory

Answer (score 0):

Since you updated your nodeJS version to a newer one, you need to update your canvas too.

run `npm install canvas` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to improper installation of node modules and can occur due to poor network conditions.
Solved this issue by deleting the nodemodules folder and doing a clean installation of node modules files by running "npm install".

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33195863)